# How can I redirect a TEdgebrowser popup window to my own form?

Tags: delphi, tedgebrowser

With the TEdgeBrowser.OnNewWindowRequested event, I can obviously tell that a new window is about to open, but how can I capture the output to my own custom TForm with a second TEdgeBrowser component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`TEdgeBrowser.OnNewWindowRequested`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.OnNewWindowRequested) event handler has a parameter named `Args` of type [`TNewWindowRequestedEventArgs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Edge.TNewWindowRequestedEventArgs), which implements Edge's [`ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs) interface. You can call its [`put_NewWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs) method, providing it with the [`ICoreWebView2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2) interface of the desired browser window, which you can get from the [`TEdgeBrowser.DefaultInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.DefaultInterface) property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's basically what I suspected, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure what I'm missing. Maybe a version issue? I'm using Delphi 10.4.1 Sydney, and there is no put_NewWindow(), but there is a Set_NewWindow(), which is what I used, Args.ArgsInterface.Set_NewWindow(EdgeBrowser2.DefaultInterface), but no joy.

Comment: Ooops! Stupid programmer trick. I got it working, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in C++Builder: Args->ArgsInterface->Set_NewWindow(WB->DefaultInterface), but put_NewWindow() did not work.

Answer (score 0):

On the event "EdgeBrowser1CreateWebViewCompleted" do the below.

```
Var s:ICoreWebView2Settings;
begin
  Sender.DefaultInterface.Get_Settings(s);
  s.Set_AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled(0);
end;
```